# Как задать логическое и в регулярном выражении?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Собственно вот регулярное выражение которое у меня получилось:

```
\/[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9]{1}[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9\.]{1,}((\?[а-яa-zА-ЯA-Z]{1,}=[0-9]{1,})|(\#[а-яa-zА-ЯA-Z]{1,})|())
```

Задумка, должно пропускать только вот такие строки

- /блаблабла
- /блабла-блабла
- /блаблабла#блаблабла
- /блаблаблбала?ывапваып=123409008098

Проблема в том что оно пропускает вот это:

- /блаблаблбала?ывапваып=

Я думаю что должно быть логическое и перед первой круглой скобкой. Как задать логическое и?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте операторы начала (`^`) и конца строки (`$`) и поправьте шаблон следующим образом:

```
/^\/[a-zа-яё0-9][-a-zа-яё0-9.]+(?:\?[а-яa-zё]+=[0-9]+|#[а-яa-zё]+)?$/iu
```

[См. демо](https://regex101.com/r/vjMRzr/2)

С помощью модификатора `i` можно не повторять буквы в противоположном регистре, а модификатор `u` позволяет обрабатывать шаблон и строки в Юникоде.

Заметьте, что `{1,}` = `+` (так короче).

Comment: Почему-то сразу не догадался, спасиб